# How to do money breakdown in Cobol

Tags: cobol

My code:

```
A-0000.

   DISPLAY "Enter Number :".
   ACCEPT NUM.
   IF NUM >=1000 THEN
       COMPUTE WS-B = NUM / 1000
       COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS-B * 500)

       IF NUM >=500 THEN
           COMPUTE WS-B = NUM / 500
           COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS-B * 500)

           IF NUM >=200 THEN
               COMPUTE WS-C = NUM / 200
               COMPUTE NUM=NUM- (WS-C * 200)

               IF NUM >=100 THEN
                   COMPUTE WS-D = NUM / 100
                   COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS-D * 100)

                   IF NUM >=50 THEN
                       COMPUTE WS-E = NUM / 50
                       COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS-E * 50)

                       IF NUM >=20 THEN
                           COMPUTE WS-F = NUM / 20
                           COMPUTE NUM = NUM- (WS-F * 20)

                           IF NUM >=10 THEN
                               COMPUTE WS-G = NUM / 10
                               COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS-G * 10)

                               IF NUM >=5 THEN
                                   COMPUTE WS-H = NUM / 5
                                   COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS-H * 5)

                                   IF NUM >=1 THEN 
                                       MOVE NUM TO WS-I

   END-IF.
```

Problem statement:

> Create a program that enters a number and determine how many of the following monetary value will be given.

```
    1, 000
    500
    200
    100
    50
    20
    10
    5
    1
```

Comment: `COMPUTE WS-B = NUM / 1000` and then do `COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS-B * 500)` seems like a bug in the code. All your `IF`s but the last (which ends in its `END-IF`) ends all together by the only `.`Note: you don't need the checks at all (depending on the input data they provide some additional cpu ticks, but I don't see that much use here) as zero multiplied by something is still zero.

Comment: Have a look at how your code looks after being formatted according to what you actually wrote. You would be better off using `DIVIDE ... INTO ... GIVING ... REMAINDER ...` here. One line per demonination instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use WS-A here instead of using WS-B twice, once for 1000's and again for 500.

```
 IF NUM >=1000 THEN
    COMPUTE WS-A = NUM / 1000
    COMPUTE NUM = NUM - (WS- * 500)
 END-IF
```

Use the END-IF scope terminator after all IF statements or you run the risk of nesting them which is not what you want to do for a sieve.